# PHP: How to execute ms sql procedure via ODBC

Tags: php, sql-server, odbc, procedure

I need to run ms sql procedure on romote server via odbc using php.
Usually, to execute some simple query like Select, insert etc i'm using:

```
$conn=odbc_connect('my_odbc','log','pass');
$sql="Select la-la";
$rs=odbc_exec($conn,$sql);
while (odbc_fetch_row($rs)) {echo..}
```

but when i'm trying to run procedure:

```
$sql="{CALL vp_getrestsforexcel(?,?)}";
```

or in other different variations - nothing happens.

Can you tell me please, what i do wrong? Thanks.